# Only last line of file written to output file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the output from a variable redirected and written into a file but only the last line from the output shows up in the file I'm writing to. However when I do a print of the variable I get all the lines I would expect.

```
rds = boto3.client('rds')
rds_instances = rds.describe_db_instances()['DBInstances']
for databases in rds_instances:
    arns = ("{0}".format(databases['DBInstanceArn']))
#    print (arns)
f = open('/tmp/arns', 'a')
f.write(arns)
f.close()
```

Example output of when I do print I get multiple rds arn's:

```
arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:222222222222:db:databasename01

arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:222222222222:db:databasename02

arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:222222222222:db:databasename03
```

However when I check the file I've written there's only:

```
arn:aws:rds:us-east-1:222222222222:db:databasename03
```

Comment: your indentation is off. those last 3 lines need to be indented. As it's written, you're only writing one line to the file- only the last value of `arns`.

Answer (score 5):

You should use a `with open(filename, mode) as f:` to [write to files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), ensuring they get closed even if exceptions happen.

As soon as the code leaves the block below the `with` your file will be auto-closed - no need to do it manually.

You could reformulate your code like this:

```
rds = boto3.client('rds')
rds_instances = rds.describe_db_instances()['DBInstances']
with open('/tmp/arns', 'a') as f:
    for databases in rds_instances:
        arns = ("{0}".format(databases['DBInstanceArn']))
        f.write(arns + '\n') # indented so it is executed foreach "for" loop
```

You might also addd a `'\n'` to your write output - it is not automatically added.

Answer (score 1):

When you print the results it prints the value of `arns` for every single time the loop runs.

And when you're writing the value into the file it will only take the value of `arns` the last time the loop runs.

What you can do is open the file before the loop and write the value within the loop instead of doing it after. Then close the file after the loop.